# Is it possible to get a smooth CSS transition through 0 degrees with transform:rotate(Xdeg)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, css-transforms

I have a React application with an icon on a Leaflet map, and a value between 0 and 359 to indicate it's current direction.

I want to `transform: rotate(Xdeg)` the icon and use `transition` to make it animate this rotation.

My problem is that when the value passes `0` (or `360`), the transition happens in the opposite direction.

Is it possible to change a box with `transform: rotate(340deg)` to `transform: rotate(10deg)` and have it rotate clockwise?

Example CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEMEbe)

```
const App = () => {
  const [rotation, setRotation] = React.useState(340);

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div>
        <div className="box-wrapper">
          {/* Here is where I'm setting the rotation CSS transform dynamically */}
          <div className="box" style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)` }}>
            <span>{ `Rotation: ${rotation}deg` }</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation((rotation + 10) % 360)}>+10 deg</button>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation(((360 + (rotation - 10)) % 360))}>-10 deg</button>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation(340)}>340 deg</button>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation(20)}>20 deg</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "spinning" effect shows because you are using a modulo operator in your calculation. Every time you hit the boundary of 0 or 359 it flips. If you remove the modulo operator in your calculation and use it instead only for showing the degree value, than it should work just fine.

I created a modifed version of your [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEWamy).

```
const App = () => {
  const [rotation, setRotation] = React.useState(340);
  function setRotation1(val) {
    let angle = rotation % 360;
    let diff = (360 - (angle - val))%360;

    if(diff > 180) {
      diff = (360-diff);
      setRotation(rotation - diff);
    } else {
      setRotation(rotation + diff);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="demo">
        <div className="box-wrapper">
          {/* Here is where I'm setting the rotation CSS transform dynamically */}
          <div className="box" style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)` }}>
            <span>{ `Rotation: ${(360+(rotation%360))%360}deg` }</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation(rotation + 10)}>+10 deg</button>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation(rotation - 10)}>-10 deg</button>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation1(340)}>340 deg</button>
        <button onClick={() => setRotation1(20)}>20 deg</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Edit:** I updated the code based on conversation in the comments.

Comment: The modulus is just my bad example sorry.. I'm getting a prop `heading`, and need to use it as the rotation value.  It's guaranteed to be in the range `{0..359}`, and specifies the direction explicitly...

Comment: You can still use the signed angles for rotating. In the initialization you then use the modulo operator `React.useState((360+angle)%360)` and before you store the value or pass it anywhere you perform the same number transformation.

Comment: Are you able to tweak your example to accommodate the `rotation` value being a prop?  Eg: `const App = ({rotation})` and have that work if the value changes from 340 to 10?

Comment: I updated the example and added a function that calculates the shortest path to the set angle.